# 27GB Size - Visual Studio

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, ionic-framework

I have used PhpStorm my entire life but now I am very much inspired by AngularJS and ionic so I am learning to code hybrid mobile apps. I downloaded the Visual Studio and installed and it already had around 6GB.

Now I need to download additional **Cross Platform Mobile Development** package but it looks like I need to download additional 27GB.

Do I really need to download this huge file? I genuinely need from pros whether I need to download entire package or I can skip few. Internet speed sucks here in India and on the downloading another 27GB AngularJS 3 will be out.

[Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaCpC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all absolutely you don't have to download all them plugin.. second if you want you caan use other good IDE as maybe Visual studio Code

```
https://code.visualstudio.com/
```

But if you want to use `Visual Studio` (as I'm doing ..but because i also develop the back end in Asp.Net WebAPI 2) .. you can skip the installation of (SO DON'T HAVE TO INSTALL) for ionic development:

- `C#/Xamarin` (it's for develop other kind of Cross Platform Mobile Development .. not Hybrid)
- `Miscorsoft Visual Studio Emulator` (you can use the Ionic tools from command line .. es: `ionic serve --lab` or also run it on your device and attach them to your browser to debug)